# Web Accessibility Error

Tags: colorbox

When using https://wave.webaim.org/ to check a page for accessibility It detects (3) red errors. seems this is all coming from colorbox  jquery.colorbox.min.js
3x empty button

```js
<button type="button" id="cboxPrevious">
<button type="button" id="cboxNext">
<button id="cboxSlideshow">
```

How can this be repaired? I know that the button type should be Some Content 
Not

Comment: Did you execute the check without the offending code?

Comment: (Do the tags ever get closed? Are they *supposed* to be nested?)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as you.. All I did was to disable a plugin called Yith compare..

Comment: This would be better as a comment (when you can do that) and welcome to stack overflow!